# RUST - в цикле читать файлы

Tags: rust

Тыкните пожалуйста носом. Начинаю разбираться в Rust. Не могу понять как в внутри цикла использовать переменную.

```
fn main() {
    for e in glob("./*.json").expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {

       let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap();

    }
}
```

Не понимаю пока синтаксис let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap();

Если так делаю - ругается:

> let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap();
>       |                                  ^ the trait `std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for
>   `std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>`

Comment: Нужно сперва получить путь к файлу из Result-переменной например с помощью match, в документации пример есть https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Давно не видел здесь русских растовцев) начнем*

***`Не понимаю пока синтаксис let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap();`***

`let` начало описания переменной

`mut` переменная может изменятся ниже по коду, переменные без `mut` могут лишь быть одноразово инициализированы при описании.

`file` имя переменной

`=` думаю уже понятно, присваивание. коротко и попроще: связывания значения с именем (в данном случаи `file`)

**Теперь ответ, а что мы связываем?**

1. `File` В данном случаи это `std::fs::File` (обязательно читайте документацию и книги по rust) https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html . Кототко и понятно: файловый поток данных связан с нашем именем `file`.
2. `std::fs::File::open(...)`, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open  Функция по `открытию файла` или `создание дескриптора файлового потока`
3. `std::fs::File::open(...)` вернет `Result<File>` , это `std::io::Result`. `Result` является перечислением (`enum`) которое хранит в себе ответ при `положительном` результате или `отрицательном` (по научному, это некоторое подобие `union` с индексом значения которое записано сейчас). `Result` придуман как хорошая замена исключений, которых в расте нет и не надо!
4. Функция `.unwrap()` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap . Проверяет перечисление `Result`, если оно имеет положительный ответ значит надо распаковать перечисление `Result` и достать из него наш `std::fs::File`, в отрицательном случаи происходит паника (поток подыхает и скорее всего ваша прога завершается).

***`Если так делаю - ругается:
let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap(); | ^ the trait std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path> is not implemented for std::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>`***

Читайте что вам говорит компилятор, он говорит по существу:) 
Вам точно надо почитать книгу, например эту (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/index.html https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/index.html , на русском можно найти)

Компилятор говорит что `трейт` `AsRef<Path>` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) не реализован для типа `Result<PathBuf, Err>`. Нет, в данном случаи вам не надо его реализовать для этого типа, бо ваша программа скорее не верна:))

Посмотрев на целиком код,

```rust
fn main() {
    for e in glob("./*.json").expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
       let mut file = File::open(e).unwrap();
    }
}
```

`e` в данном случаи не является чистым значением, он является `Result<Data, Err>`! Вам надо распаковать, тоесть проверить `Result` можете воспользоватся темже `expect` который у вас. `expect` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), функция делает тоже самое что и `unwrap` но она более информативна так как выводит текст ошибки ровно тот что вы `напишите` при ошибке.

Если вы использовать начали `expect` то может зачем вам `unwarp` и лучше написать ровно так как надо?

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    for e in glob("./*.json").expect("Err, Failed to read glob pattern...") {

        let mut file = File::open(e.expect("Err, glob data...")).expect("Err open file...");

    }
}
```

**Play:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77d91596733d7785c8681e5074b199ce

`#Ulin19` `#Ulin1920`

Comment: ))) вот решил начать rust изучать. Нравится он мне своими отличия и от C.

Answer (score 1):

У вас `e` имеет тип
`core::result::Result<std::path::PathBuf, glob::GlobError>`.
Иными словами, результатный тип.  Вам надо обработать ошибку.  Самое
тупое и опасное:

```rust
fn main() {
    for f in glob::glob("./*.rs").expect("failed to read glob pattern") {
        let mut file = fs::File::open(f.unwrap()).unwrap();
    };
}
```